# How to design meaningful objects and their relationships in simple physic simulations

Tags: oop, fortran, physics, fortran2003

I'm trying to design some simple live simulations using an OOP paradigm. The problem I'm facing is that due to my lack of experience in this approach, I don't know how to define in a natural way the "right" objects and their relationships. Thus, my question is closer to software architecture, rather than a more technical "how can achieve this or that". Note that I'm doing this exercise precisely to learn about this programming paradigm.

The simulation tries to resolve the interactions (collisions, attraction, etc) between particles in an empty 2D space. The first object that comes to my mind is `Particle`. I have implemented this class with the position, velocity, mass, etc. I have created methods to initiate them, update their position (according to some physical rules) or even draw them in the canvas. Now, my problem comes when setting the physical constants or the plotting parameters (canvas size, window number, frames per second, etc). Right now I'm using global variables such as the gravity or the canvas size. This is what one would do in non-OOP approach, and it works os far. But I was struggling thinking on how a pure OOP would deal with this shared parameters among particles. I can foresee various options.

1. I could create the class `Canvas`, with the graphical parameters, and `Universe` with the constants such as gravity. Then, the class `Particle` would be an extended class. But from which should I heritage? Still, the class would get extended, but not the objects themselves...
2. Another option could be to create the `Universe` and `Particle` as independent classes. Then, I would relate them by creating a unique Universe object. Each Particle would contain a pointer to such Universe object, so they have access to the physical parameters. I'm not sure if this pointer approach is even OOP at all...

Although I'm aware that there are many ways to do this, I wonder if there is one which is the more intuitive and "standard" at least from an academic point of view. I guess it is not included in the solutions I propose, so any hint on how to design the structure in this type of simple simulations would be very welcome.

Comment: Be careful : OOP and performance may be difficult to combine. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/125753/does-object-orientation-really-affect-algorithm-performance

Answer (score 1):

This is a more practical take on it, mostly from my own experience, and strictly attempted at the level of basic design considerations. I would be just as interested in feedback.

First, from the design point of view your "*Canvas*" and "*Universe*" seem different: I can imagine that *Canvas* parameters may need to change, while physical constants presumably would not.

With the assumption that *Canvas* entities may change, for me that would be a separate class. I don't see that you would want your *Particle* to inherit from this; in my understanding these are logically completely separate entities. As for convenience in puting particles on the canvas, I would handle that at a different level, not by inheritance.

The *Particle* itself may well be implemented with a hierarchy of classes, but this depends on your project and whether you have different kinds (or behaviors) of particles.

As for the fixed parameters, I have used separate header files with explicit name spaces in `C++` projects. I don't see a reason that this wouldn't be a feasible design in Fortran, to use a separate module with constants. In that sense they are global, but that can be controlled in use, and that is what they are.  There is flexibility in that approach as well, in case your set(s) of constants develop more complexity than just being a handful of numbers. Also, you can later elevate this to a class if a need for that is demonstrated.

Then there are questions of how exactly these relate to other classes, and of the many details in how to write them.  That would take the question elsewhere, and I am not as familiar with Fortran's full OO capabilities (other than writing classes).

So I would say: "*Canvas*" is a class and "*Universe*" is a module, both separate from *Particle*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still my concern is, how do I relate "Universe" and "Canvas"? I'll put a simple examle: a real problem I have is that the canvas has an id that identifies the window (this id is used for the low level plotting subroutines). I have a method within "Particle" that draws a circle in the given coordinates, but it needs such id. How can I make a particle aware of the fact that it "lives" in a given "Canvas"? In my current implementation, such id is part of the class "Particle", which I consider a lame solution.

Comment: @Onturenio  I wouldn't include these considerations at the design level.  Why would _Particle_ be entangled with the _Canvas_? It is merely being plotted, yes? Its behavior is not influenced by _Canvas_, correct? If it needs to know about _Canvas_ propeties -- well, _Canvas_ is a class with the interface you design (methods for access) , so everyone can fetch information they may need.  You can integrate them more tightly, but making either a part of the inheritance chain of another strikes me as unsuitable.

Comment: @Onturenio  I ran into this interesting question while reviewing my older posts.  What did you end up doing? I'd also suggest to post that, as an answer for future visitors to this page. (It's OK if it's short and  your own, if that's the best.)